# Resharper: "Expression always true"

Tags: javascript

Why is [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) saying that the expression is alwaus true? It's `!!bar` that is highlighted.

I would say that if it should say anything at all about it, it could say that it's always false. Or am I loosing my mind?

```
function foo(bar){
     bar = !bar ? !!bar : bar;
}
```

My thought here is that if `bar` is `undefined`, it will evaluate to `false` and be converted to a `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer why resharper says that, but if what you want is to coerce the value into a booolean, couldn't you rewrite it `bar = !!bar`?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I thought it would throw an exception when bar was undefined. But it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Johan: there's a difference between having a variable/argument with the value `undefined` and there actually being no defined variable with that name. The difference between your original code and this version is that if the value being passed is truthy, it will be converted to `true` while with your original code it would remain as-is.

Comment: I know it's not equivalent, since it will always change the value to true/false. But it thought that was what he wanted. Then again, it doesn't change the truth value of the variable so I'm unclear on the use case.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Well, the end result would still be the same. A boolean casted to bool wouldn't really matter. It will be passed either as a bool or undefined

Comment: @Johan: ah, I see. I was just thinking about if it wasn't a boolean, but that point seems to be moot.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yea my bad, should have mentioned that in the question.